# Find a parabola with 3 given points defined in f(x)= sin x

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $\frac{π}{3} , \frac{π}{2} , \frac{2π}{3}$ the points where the parabola $ax^2+bx+c$ passes through, they are also defined in $f(x)=\sin (x)$ . If I expand the Taylor polynomial of the three given values until the third term I get a quadratic expression for each value:

$\sin(x)= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(x-\fracπ3)-\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}(x-\fracπ3)^2$

$\sin(x)= 1 + -\frac{1}{2}(x-\fracπ3)^2$

$\sin(x)= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}(x-\fracπ3)-\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}(x-\fracπ3)^2$

How can I get a parabola using the the three expansions from above?
I'm just a math beginner, so if there's anything wrong let me know, I will be very thankful

Comment: Taylor to the second degree will given you a parabola that is tangent to the sinusoid and has the same curvature, but not passing by three given points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost as you wrote, you want $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ going through the three data points. Replacing, you then have

$$\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)=a\left(\frac\pi3\right)^2+b\left(\frac\pi3\right)+c$$
$$\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)=a\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2+b\left(\frac\pi2\right)+c$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi} 3\right)=a\left(\frac{2\pi} 3\right)^2+b\left(\frac{2\pi} 3\right)+c$$ Replace the left hand sides by the values of the sine.

Now you have three linear equations to solve for $a,b,c$. If you have problems with this, let me know. In fact, we could use the symmetry around $x=\frac\pi2$ to make the problem simpler to solve; be sure, it is quite easy.

I do not see exactly  what Taylor could do here for you.

**Edit**

The equations are so simple 
$$\frac{\pi ^2 a}{9}+\frac{\pi  b}{3}+c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\pi ^2 a}{4}+\frac{\pi  b}{2}+c=1\tag 2$$
$$\frac{4 \pi ^2 a}{9}+\frac{2 \pi  b}{3}+c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag 3$$ that any method would solve them very quickly; for sure, matrix calculation would be the most elegant way but even successive eliminations would be simple.

For example, subtract $(1)$ from  $(2)$; this will give $$\frac{5 \pi ^2 a}{36}+\frac{\pi  b}{6}=1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag 4$$ Subrtact $(3)$ from  $(2)$; this will give $$-\frac{7 \pi ^2 a}{36}-\frac{\pi  b}{6}=1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag 5$$ Add $(4)$ and $(5)$ $$-\frac{\pi ^2 a}{18}=2-\sqrt{3}\implies a=\frac{18 \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)}{\pi ^2}$$ Reuse $(4)$ to get $b$ and then $(1)$ to get $c$. At the end, you finish with
$$a=\frac{18 \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)}{\pi ^2} \qquad b=\frac{18 \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)}{\pi } \qquad c=\frac{9 \sqrt{3}}{2}-8$$ For sure, mor fancy would be Lagrange interpolation as shown by Felix Marin in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time, what would be the best  method to get a, b, c? I think Gauss-Jordan may work. Could you suggest me another?

Comment: I shall edit my answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The straightforward approach is to use
>   '$\ds{\color{#f00}{Lagrange\ Interpolation}}$'. Write the following expression:

\begin{align}
\mc{L}\pars{x} & \equiv
A\pars{x - {\pi \over 2}}\pars{x - {2\pi \over 3}} +
B\pars{x - {\pi \over 3}}\pars{x - {2\pi \over 3}} +
C\pars{x - {\pi \over 3}}\pars{x - {\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}
By replacing successively $\ds{x = \pi/3\,,\ \pi/2\,,\ 2\pi/3}$ you'll get:
$$
\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\sin\pars{\pi \over 3}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{A\pars{{\pi \over 3} - {\pi \over 2}}\pars{{\pi \over 3} - {2\pi \over 3}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sin\pars{\pi \over 2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{B\pars{{\pi \over 2} - {\pi \over 3}}\pars{{\pi \over 2} - {2\pi \over 3}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sin\pars{2\pi \over 3}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{C\pars{{2\pi \over 3} - {\pi \over 3}}\pars{{2\pi \over 3} - {\pi \over 2}}}
\end{array}\right\}
\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{A} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}{9\root{3} \over \pi^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{B} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,{36 \over \pi^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{C} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}{9\root{3} \over \pi^{2}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\mc{L}\pars{x} = ax^{2} + bx + c\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
\ds{a} & \ds{=} & \ds{A + B + C} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{36 - 18\root{3} \over \pi^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{b} & \ds{=} & \ds{{\pi \over 6}\pars{-7A - 6B - 5C}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-}18\,{2 - \root{3} \over \pi}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{c} & \ds{=} & \ds{{\pi^{2} \over 18}\pars{6A + 4B + 3C}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\pars{8 - {9 \over 2}\,\root{3}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
The interpolation becomes:
$$\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{
\mc{L}\pars{x} = -\,{36 - 18\root{3} \over \pi^{2}}\,x^{2} +
18\,{2 - \root{3} \over \pi}\,x - \pars{8 - {9 \over 2}\,\root{3}}}}
$$
An *error estimation* is given by:
$$
\root{\ds{\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\verts{\sin\pars{x} - \mc{L}\pars{x}}^{\, 2}
\,\dd x} \over
\ds{\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\sin^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}} \approx
5.1528 \times 10^{-4}
$$